# Laravel how to break where chain

Tags: laravel

I have one "main" query, and I want to break It's chain and share data to the different cases;

```
$products = Product::where('is_active', 1)->where('date', '>', $blabla);
```

I want to split It's data like:

```
$type_1 = $products->where('type', 1)->groupBy('x')->orderBy('x')->get();
$type_2 = $products->where('type', 2)->groupBy('x')->orderBy('x')->get();
$type_3 = $products->where('type', 3)->groupBy('x')->orderBy('x')->get();
```

But when I generate this code,
It let It to the chain, and $type_2 never returns. Because It searches inside type_1.

What's wrong with that logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `where` on `$products` multiple times, the conditions will always overlap. For example, when you execute the first line, the condition is `type = 1`, and when you execute the second line, the condition becomes  `type = 1 and type = 2`, when you execute the third line, the condition is `type = 1 and type = 2 and type = 3`.

You can use `clone` to `clone` a new instance of `$products`, like this:

```
$type_1 = $products->where('type', 1)->groupBy('x')->orderBy('x')->get();
$type_2 = (clone $products)->where('type', 2)->groupBy('x')->orderBy('x')->get();
$type_3 = (clone $products)->where('type', 3)->groupBy('x')->orderBy('x')->get();
```

Comment: that worked. but I needed to change type_1 to (clone $products) too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by following approch, Its efficient way as well.

`$products = Product::where('is_active', 1)->where('date', '>', $blabla)->get();`

```
$type_1 = $products->where('type', 1)->groupBy('x')->sortBy('x');
$type_2 = $products->where('type', 2)->groupBy('x')->sortBy('x');
$type_3 = $products->where('type', 3)->groupBy('x')->sortBy('x');
```